# Blender Viewport dislay a better image than actually rendering the image. What could cause this?

Tags: rendering

I'm a first time blender user and I'm following a tutorial to recreate the "Backrooms" in blender. When I render my image however the ceiling is textured weirdly and there is a horizontal line throughout the image, [image: as can be seen here]

I've been trying to figure out the cause of the different render result but I haven't been able to wrap my head around it. What settings might cause this?

Comment: On the ceiling there seems to be duplicate geometry, the black artifacts look like Z-fighting. Is there a second ceiling which is disabled in viewport but shows in render? And the horizontal line... well, hard to tell without the file, it could be many things. But most of the time when something's wrong with the render that seems okay in the viewport, it's hidden objects or settings which are different for viewport and render.

Comment: sorry, but without seeing any of your settings/geometry we can just guess around as Gordon did. If you really want to know the cause for this...you should provide your blend file

Comment: As Gordon said, there was a duplicate object present. Thank you very much, this solved the issue :) And @Chris for future questions I will make sure to provide more information/attach .blend files.

Answer (score 1):

From Gordon Brinkmann's comment:

On the ceiling there seems to be duplicate geometry, the black artifacts look like Z-fighting.

There is a second ceiling present.

[image]

Upon disabling this the issues are resolved.

[image]